# What is field "website_root" in the database table "cms_page" in CE1.9

Tags: cms, magento-1.9, database

I am working on multistore functionality. 
I am referring cms page module for reference. 
I found "website_root" field in "cms_page" table  but not in the table "cms_block" table. 
What is field "website_root" in the database table "cms_page"?

Comment: I didn't see it in the installation of CE1.9 I have. Could it be from an extension?

Comment: @Sander Mangel - its from installation of CE1.9 . I installed Sample Data ver 1.9.0.0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be some left over extra column from the database of whoever made the sample data. I can confirm it is in the data, but I think it can be removed because:

1. It is never used in the code, it is also not added via a setup script,
2. It is not in older versions of Magento including the sample data,

Or to be honest simply ignoring it would be fine. If you are starting developing your old store then I would suggest using a clean database anyway and not the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not in magento 1.9.0.1 original.

And if it is from the sample data, only god knows where it is from.